# error al usar proxy y mostrar en consola la funcion pasada

Tags: javascript, function, class, proxy

estoy teniendo un problema con una parte del codigo donde paso una funcion al proxy e intercepto los valores dado

```
class bridge {}
bridge.__proto__ = new Proxy(bridge, {
    get: (o, k) => o[k],
    set: (o, k, v)=> o[k]
})
class Data extends bridge {}
console.log(Data)
```

[image: error]

se hace un bucle infinito y ya he de todo, este es un ejemplo de codigo de lo que hago

Comment: Hola @rocky intento replicar lo que te pasa pero no me entra en el bucle que muestras

Comment: @jorgeGomez hola gracias por responde disculpa creo que no puse bien el codigo de ejemplo. ya cambia y puse una parte de mi codigo

Comment: perdona, pero sigue sin replicarse el error. intenta probar lo que vas a poner en la publicación que se replique el error para poder revisar y ayudarte

Comment: @jorgeGomez disculpa ya encontre el error y es que al llamar console.log(Data) proxy llama la funcion get y los valores pasado a dicha funcion que me muestra como primer parametro es este Symbol(Symbol.toPrimitive) y como segundo parametro es el objecto de referencia la clase Data y se repite de nuevo llamando la clase padre, lo cual se me ejecuta dos veces, y al usar el segundo valor que me pasa que es el objeto de referencia del proxy se me hacia un bucle infinito.. lo resolvi con una comprobacion. muchas gracias por responder, lo que trabajo es para un framework web.